# What do SC and UC mean in the figure details?

Tags: streetpass, super-street-fighter-iv-3d-edition

Each figure for SSF IV 3D has "SC" and "UC" stats below "AT" (which I assume is Attack).  What do these stats mean for a StreetPass Battle, and can I improve them?

Answer (score 1):

SC = Super Combo meter (max 4 bars); UC = Ultra Combo meter (max 2 bars).

You will get variants for each figure. Some will have SC and UC bars filled. If you have a figurine with one of these, it will have already one or more SC/UC parts ready to use right at the start of a StreetPass match.

Only Power, Defense, and Speed can all be altered for a given figure, up to 300.

Comment: What are SC/UC parts?

Comment: Parts of your SC/UC meter?

Comment: Ah!  How does the meter fill up?

Comment: It's automatic. You have no control over in the StreetPass battles.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing

- Super Combo
- Ultra Combo

? I haven't played the version, but it's SF4.

Comment: OK.  But how in the world would these stats affect the Street Pass figure battles?

Comment: No idea. Maybe the stat reflects how many you've done?

Comment: Here is a video showing a SFIV StreetPass battle: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-skcuwzp5Mg.  As you can see, the player has no opportunity to excute combos.

Comment: Oh. I didn't even know something like that existed. -.- It might just be a rating of how strong those would be that contributes to who wins, but I really have no clue.